# Let $A$ and $R$ be rings and $f : A → R$ a ring homomorphism.(almost similar to the other question I've asked)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $R$ be rings and $f : A → R$ a ring homomorphism. Give a concrete example of $A, R$ and a ring homomorphism $f : A → R$ such that $A$ has unity and $R$ does **not** have unity.

I can think of such rings are $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$, but I can't construct $f$ here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb Z$ and $R=A\times 2\mathbb Z$ and map $1\mapsto (1,0)$.

Comment: +1 The idea here is to have $R = A \times B$, where $B$ does not have a unity.

Comment: @abcd1234 I did. $f$ maps 1 to $(1,0)$.

Comment: @abcd1234 What I said above means $f(1)=(1,0)$. This uniquely determines the homomorphism. In general, $f(n)=(n,0)$.

Comment: @abcd1234 no problem.